# rvm install ree looks for /opt/local on Mountain Lion with XCode - but I don't have MacPorts

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am unable to install Ruby REE with

```
rvm install ree
```

because the compiler and linker are looking for /opt/local. All I have in /opt/local is X11, because I don't use MacPorts.

I installed my C/C++ compilers with the XCode command-line tools, not with https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer. (Because I want XCode available to me and they are not compatible.)

The first reference to /opt/local in the rvm install log is:

```
make PREINCFLAGS='-I/opt/local/include' PRELIBS='-L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-rpath,/Users/brian/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib -L/Users/brian/.rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/lib -lsystem_allocator'
```

From there I get numerous errors about files it can't find in /opt/local/include and /opt/local/lib (because those directories do not exist on my system).

I don't know why the installer thinks it will find header files or libs in /opt/local, nor can I figure out how to get it to look in the right places.

Here are my GNU C++ and C compilers:

```
/usr/bin$ ll g+* gcc*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  12 Feb  4 11:58 g++@ -> llvm-g++-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  12 Feb  4 12:16 g++-4.2@ -> llvm-g++-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  12 Feb  4 11:58 gcc@ -> llvm-gcc-4.2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  12 Jan  6 21:11 gcc-4.2@ -> llvm-gcc-4.2
```

I use Homebrew, but I didn't install anything compiler-related:

```
/usr/bin$ brew list
ack         coreutils   geoip       gnupg       libevent    little-cms2 ossp-uuid   qt          tmux
autoconf    ctags       gettext     htop-osx    libpng      macvim      phantomjs   readline    tree
automake    fontconfig  ghostscript imagemagick libtiff     memcached   pkg-config  redis       wget
cmake       freetds     gist        jbig2dec    libtool     mysql       postgresql  sqlite      xz
colordiff   freetype    git         jpeg        libyaml     ngrep       pstree      tig
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to get past this. All the stuff about /opt/local was a red herring. The fact that I don't have /opt/local was not causing any problems.

The real problem was farther down in the [install.log](https://gist.github.com/4710123):

```
/usr/include/tk.h:78:23: error: X11/Xlib.h: No such file or directory
```

The fix is to use `--without-tk --without-tcl` when installing ree:

```
rvm install ree --without-tk --without-tcl
```

I'm still having other unrelated problems installing ree, but at least this part is no longer a problem.